# Unwanted padding with Combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to line up my text and combobox in a nice straight line, vertically-aligned to middle, with an HRule underneath it.

It works great until I add a combobox which seems to add some padding I can't get rid of. Meaning, I'm now a few pixels further away from the HRule.

Where does it come from and how can I get rid of it?

Here's my code:

```
<s:HGroup>

<mx:Image
    visible="{meetingList_vs.selectedIndex==0}"
    includeInLayout="{meetingList_vs.selectedIndex==0}"
    source="{arrow}"
    width="5"
    height="10"/>

<s:Label 
    left="0" 
    text="{ 'In Progress and Upcoming ' + '(' + model.generalInfo.upcomingMeetingList.length + ')'}" 
    styleName="groupTitleLabel"
    buttonMode="true"
    click="{meetingList_vs.selectedIndex=0}"/>

<s:Label 
    left="0" 
    text="for"
    styleName="groupTitleLabel"/>

<s:ComboBox 
    id="selectedUser" 
    width="125"
    height="25"
    borderVisible="false"/>
```

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Screenshot may help here; telling us what you want vs what you're getting.  I'm confused by the question too.  You want to line up text and a ComboBox; which works until you add a ComboBox?  Is there a second ComboBox you're adding?  Or does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the padding to 0 on the ComboBox? The [default](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html) for the paddingBottom style is 3.

```
<s:ComboBox paddingBottom="0" />
```

Comment: That did the trick; didn't realize the paddingBottom was that high as default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
```

or another appropriate setting for verticalAlign e.g. "baseline"